# Filling a dateframe in python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have so far created a data frame in python which looks like this:

```
     NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24  \
datum_von                                                                      
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-10          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-11          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2017-10-11          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

I would like to fill this data frame with some operations. I am trying to use the following code but it doesn't work.

```
prod = 0
dias = 0
x = 0
for prod in Products:
    for dias in range(len(df_.index)):
        df_.loc['dias']['prod'] = 1
```

It is simple but I a not quite getting how to use nested loops to fill this data frame.Also, I tried this solution:

```
for prod in Products:
    for dias in range(len(df_.index)):
        df_.loc[dias][prod] = 1
```

My error is: `**TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <type 'int'>**`

```
**KeyError: 'the label [dias] is not in the [index]'**
```

Comment: How does it "not work".  Do you get an error or something else?

Comment: Yes, here is the info about my data frame <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 192 entries, 2017-10-10 to 2017-10-25
Data columns (total 12 columns):
dtypes: int64(12)
memory usage: 19.5+ KB  **Error: KeyError: 'the label [days] is not in the [index]'**

Comment: Why don't you edit your question with that.

Comment: good idea! I did it

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to fill product columns with 1s? If so, rather than iterating over rows, it would be easier to use apply on the given column you want.

Comment: no, I will do some operations that you probably give different numbers but I was just testing if it was filing and was not

Answer (score 0):

I figured out

```
for prod in Products:
    if k == len(Products):
        break
    for dias in y:
         df_.ix[dias, prod] = 3
    k=k+1
```